# Add last value of 'Append Changes to Existing Text' to a column

Tags: list

How do I add the last value of 'Append Changes to Existing Text' data to a column.
i.e. Say I have a Column A with data 123 but it has changed to 456. Now, I want data 123 which is the previous value in a column. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 'Append Changes to Existing Text' column is storing each of it's values in the different versions of the list item, and then just collecting all of these for display.

To get the previous value you have to loop through [SPListItem.Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx) and then get the value from the latest SPListItemVersion through the [Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415302)